# How to create a EASY custom seekbar for music player in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Code in the form of connecting a melody and creating instances ..

```
import flash.events.Event;
var mySound:Sound = new MyFavSong();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0; 
var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
myChannel = mySound.play();
myTransform.volume = 1; 
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform; 
stop();
```

And then play buttons, pauses, sound stops + volume
Stop

```
 stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStop);
    function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
    myChannel.stop();
    lastPosition = 0;
    stop();
    }
```

Pause

```
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);
function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void{
lastPosition = myChannel.position;
myChannel.stop();
stop();
}
```

Play

```
 play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);
    function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void{
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
    play();
    }
```

Volume

```
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickUp);
function onClickUp(e:MouseEvent):void{
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
myTransform.volume = myTransform.volume + 1;
}
```

Please, help me

Comment: Do not use play() and stop() methods, as they will affect your main timeline (or the movieClip where your functions are declared), but not the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated progress event for soundChannel, but you can access SoundChannel.position property each frame to get current sound position in milliseconds. You may get the proportion of the seekbar by dividing the value of SoundChannel.position by Sound.length value.
See example:

```
var mySound: Sound = new MyFavSong();
var myChannel: SoundChannel = mySound.play();
var lastPosition: Number = 0;
var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
myTransform.volume = 1;
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
stop();

var totalWidth: Number = stage.stageWidth;
var barContainer: Sprite = new Sprite();
var progressBar: Shape = new Shape();
var blankBar: Shape = new Shape();
initBlankBar();
barContainer.addChild(blankBar);
barContainer.addChild(progressBar);
barContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekSound);
progressBar.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateSoundProgress);
addChild(barContainer);

function initBlankBar(): void {
    blankBar.graphics.beginFill(0xAAC7DB);
    blankBar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, totalWidth, 20);
    blankBar.graphics.endFill();
}

function updateSoundProgress(e: Event): void {
    var w: Number = (myChannel.position / mySound.length) * totalWidth;
    progressBar.graphics.clear();
    progressBar.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    progressBar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w, 20);
    progressBar.graphics.endFill();
}

function seekSound(e: MouseEvent):void {
    lastPosition = (e.localX / totalWidth) * mySound.length;
    onClickPlay(null);
}

function onClickPlay(e: MouseEvent): void {
    myChannel.stop();
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition, 0, myTransform);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need
Thank you very much!!